# Mocking configuration interfaces as a practice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a test case where I need to test an object, but that object requires a lot of configuration to work correctly.

Now I have *5 or 6* interfaces with many methods out of which only a few will be relevant for testing that object.

So the question is basically is it a proper use of Mocking framework to mock configuration related interfaces or I should implement interfaces in the test case to provide data?

```
Mockito.mock(IConfiguration.class); //is this a proper use?
```

EDIT:

I have read at some places which comment on not using mocks for mocking simple objects. In my case the objects are simple but the interface is fat. So there are plenty of methods.

Comment: If there is even one configuration setting relevant to your tests then you DO need some custom implementation. Various ways you can do this without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a very good use case since it's often not trivial to instantiate the implementations of those interfaces.

Configuration should be a very simple framework which must allow to easily create instances for tests - hundreds of thousands of different configurations per second, in fact. Or why would I need a configuration framework if my code didn't support hundreds of config options to tweak its behavior?

But unfortunately, this simple wisdom is often lost on people writing config frameworks.

Comment: @blgt: I said "implementations" :-)

Answer (score 0):

While testing any of your class that uses the implementations of your `configuration related interfaces`, you should go with the `mock` implementation of these configuration interfaces.

The `subject under test (SUT)` will call the methods of your configuration classes to does its job. So for a given input, you just need to stub the behavior of calls to the methods of  your  configuration classes before they're called from within the method that you are testing:

```
    public class ServiceTest {


    IConfiguration mockConfig;

    private ServiceUnderTest serviceUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        serviceUnderTest = new ServiceUnderTest();
        mockConfig = mock(IConfiguration.class);
        serviceUnderTest.setConfig(mockConfig);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
    //Here you can stub the behavior of method calls on "IConfiguration" before they're called
    }
}
```

As you are testing `ServiceUnderTest` unit, you don't need to have real implementations of configuration classes. You just need to stub the behavior of method calls on these configuration classes.